# Watson Speech to text - custom language model training error - Total number of OOV words exceeds 30000

Tags: speech-to-text, training-data, watson

I am getting training error for my custom language model.

I added < 30K words. I verified the count of OOV words -

{"corpora": [{
   "out_of_vocabulary_words": 73,
   "total_words": 5034,
   "name": "ABC",
   "status": "analyzed"
}]}

curl -X GET -u "myusername":"mypassword" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/my-customization-id/words" > OOV.txt

I have 21,861 words in OOV.txt.

Now, when I train the language model, I get the following error -

{
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request",
   "error": "Total number of OOV words 128858 exceeds 30000"
}

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this issue with Speech-to-Text Customization in Watson long ago.